# Unit testing in Dart with forLoops returns stackoverflow

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, for-loop, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to unit test a class and its methods. The subClass.methods generate a list of objects via a factory generator method inside a forLoop.

1. Unit testing the method I found breaks my testing environment by returning a stack overflow
2. If i remove the forloop, the unit test succeeds without problems

What is causing this break?

```dart
  final ClassA sut = ClassA();

// The suspect

  void badMethod(
    int arg1,
    int arg2,
    int arg3,
    List<ClassA> ls,
  ) {
    for (int i = arg1; i <= arg2; i + arg3) {

      /// Below is a factory generator method from the Parent class, 
      /// being used in this subclass

      ClassA t = ClassA.generate(type: 'test', trigger: i);
      ls.add(t);
    }
    return;
  }

// ----Test below

  group('info', () {

// No problems here

    test('test', () {
      final List<ClassA> r = [];

      ClassA t = ClassA.generate(type: 'test', trigger: i);
      r.add(t);

      expect(r, []);
    });

//! stackoverflow here

    test('adds object to list', () {
      final List<Tile> r = [];

      sut.badMethod(1, 1, 5, r); // <-- bad boy

      expect(r, []);
      expect(r.length, 0);

    });
  });
```

Comment: The code you've provided isn't complete, and without psychic powers, nobody knows what your code is doing.  I strongly suggest that you try distilling your code to a minimal example that can reproduce your problem.  The act of doing so very often will provide you with insight into the cause and will help you learn how to debug it yourself.

Comment: Very condescending comment aside from the fact you're trying to be helpful.@nvoigt was able to figure out the problem. So either he has "psychic powers" or you have very little experience dealing with abstractions. Thanks for your help

Comment: nvoigt managed to catch a typo that I overlooked.  However, the fact remains that when asking a question, you generally should provide [a minimal example that can reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The type of error that you reported (a stack overflow) is almost always caused by infinite recursion; it's a little surprising that that was the error in this case.

Comment: It's a class with a method that essentially generates instances of itself. That's probably why it caused a S/O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = arg1; i <= arg2; i + arg3)
```

You probably meant `i += arg3`? Otherwise your loop counter never changes.

Congratulations, your test did what it was supposed to do, it found a bug. Now you only need to learn how to debug a test and you will unleash the power of unit testing.

Comment: Haha you're a genius damn you! That was the solution exactly!! You deserve the world